# Vue function to present data to page is not functioning

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I am designing a settings page for a project. The page is HTML. I am using JSON to store data, and Vue 3 to present the data to the page. The problem that I have is that the data is being collected, but Vue is not replacing the variables. Am I doing something wrong?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:v-on="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Settings</title>
        <link href='./favicon.ico' rel='icon'>
        <script src="scripts/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="settings">
            <span>Background: {{ background }}</span><br />
            <span>Columns: {{ columns }}</span><br />
            <span>Group:</span><br/>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Width: {{ group_width }}</span><br/>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Color: {{ group_color }}</span>
        </div>
        <script src="scripts/settings.js" type="text/javascript, module"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

settings.js:

```
import Vue from './vue';

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var settings_object;
    request.open('GET', 'data/settings.json', true);
    request.send(null);
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
            settings_object = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            var bgval = settings_object.background;
            var cval = settings_object.columns;
            var gwval = settings_object.group.width;
            var gcval = settings_object.group.color;
    
            // Used exclusively for testing the colloction of data.
            alert('Background: ' + bgval + '\n' +
            'Columns: ' + cval + '\n' +
            'group_width' + gwval);
    
            new Vue({
                el: '#settings',
                data: {
                    background: bgval,
                    columns: cval,
                    group_width: gwval,
                    group_color: gcval,
                },
            });
        }
    };
```

settings.json:

```
{
    "background": "connected_dots",
    "columns": 2,
    "group": {
        "width": 3,
        "color": "custom"
    }
}
```

Comment: your doing it wrong.. move the xhr call to settings inside the app in the created() hook, also if your using Vue 3 there is no new Vue

Comment: You lost me at xhr... Cross ? Request I'm guessing. Also what? Hook? I'm also confused by the no new Vue. Do you have a refernece? Source? Anything, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lawrence Cherone is right the XMLHttpRequest() need to be inside the hook like created() or mounted().
After XHR call you assign values from the hook by:

```
this.yourVariableDefinedInData = value.
```

Note the

```
.bind(this)
```

is necessary to have correct "this" in scope of

```
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
```

This should work:

```
var vueMain = new Vue({
    el: '#vue-main',
    data: {
        background: '',
        columns: '',
        group_width: '',
        group_color: '',
    },
    computed: {
        field0: function(){
            var classCss = 'field margin-mobile-fix';
            if (this.expandBaseData===false){
                classCss += ' hidden';
                // vueMenu.menuVisible=false;
            }else{
                classCss +=" opacity0 hidden-show";
                // vueMenu.menuVisible=true;
            }
            return classCss;
        },
    },
    mounted() {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var settings_object;
            request.open('GET', 'data/settings.json', true);
            request.send(null);
            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
                    settings_object = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                    this.bgval = settings_object.background;
                    this.cval = settings_object.columns;
                    this.gwval = settings_object.group.width;
                    this.gcval = settings_object.group.color;
                    alert('Background: ' + this.bgval + '\n' +
                    'Columns: ' + this.cval + '\n' +
                    'group_width' + this.gwval);
                }
            }.bind(this)
}
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I should be ashamed. I was working with vue2 and switched to vue3 without looking through the changes.